# Saving memory to file and loading it without having to parse the data?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

My program has to process a large data file and create lookup tables in memory so that it can access records in the file without having to search through the file. For example, it makes an array of structure [name, seekLocation] and sorts it alphabetically so that faster search algorithms can be implemented.

Instead of having to create this lookup table every time the program is run, is it possible to make this table once and save it into a file?

Of course, one way would be to do just that. Save it into file and load it, parse it and fill up the structures in a loop.

But say I don't want to save it as data that needs to be parsed. I want to save the whole block of memory which contains the array in a raw binary file. Then I can load the file in memory, define a pointer to the start of that block and address all elements.

How would I go about doing that? Do operating systems or languages specifically prohibit doing it(for security issues, maybe)? If they don't, are there some libraries or code to help me do it?

If it is possible, is it also possible to do so with disjointed pieces of data (linked list)?

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful. Thank you.

I am using C++ in Linux.

Comment: If the data contains pointers then you can't just dump it and re-load it. And remember pointers can be hidden in things like *std strings* or *std vectors*. Even if it doesn't contain pointers there are things that can trip you up.

Comment: @Galik Yes, I probably wouldn't be able to work with pointers, but if it's just a block of data, I don't see why it wouldn't be theoretically possible to do.

Comment: If it's "plain old data" (essentially just primitive types) then it should work but there are gotchas. The binary data file is not guaranteed to be compatible across systems (obviously) but also it may not even be compatible with the same program compiled using different flags or with a later version of the compiler. Not that those things necessarily change often but there are no guarantees if they do.

Comment: "is it also possible to do so with disjointed pieces of data (linked list)". The answer to that is obviously no as follows from the above comments because linked lists contain pointers.

Comment: @Galik The memory dump is not meant to be something shared or permanent. It's just a tweak to start the program start faster. Fall backs and security checks will have to be written, obviously, for cases when it fails. Do you have any idea on how I might approach this problem in code?

Comment: Well, without knowing specifics, you could put a version code and build number (date/time of compilation?/ git hash?) as the first thing in the data block so you know to ignore reading the dump if a new version of the program is loading an old data block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about serialization/deserialization.

If your principal class implementing the 'sorted' table can be described as a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) message then the dump and reload stage will be trivial.

The main steps will be:

1. create a [myclass.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) file and describe the structure in it
2. compile myclass.proto with protoc (under linux, install the appropriate protobuf packages). This should generate myclass.pb.cpp and myclass.pb.h
3. use this class in a wrapper class
4. implement 'load' & 'save' in your wrapper class

Something like that :

```
#include "myclass.pb.h"
class wrapper
{
    myclass _protobuf_data;
  public:
    void load(std::string filename)
    {
      std::fstream input(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
      // add some err managt here (file not exists, etc.)
      _protobuf_data.ParseFromIstream(&input);  // <<= reload file          
    }

    void save(std::string filename)
    {
      fstream output(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
      _protobuf_data.SerializeToOstream(&output);  // <<= save file     
    }


};
```

Comment: Cool. This is slightly more complicated than what I had hoped but the kind of thing I needed. Thanks.

Comment: the added value is step 1, the other stuff is just plumbing.